# Access denied when trying to view path of xml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am trying to get the path for an xml file i created in my lightswitch application. however i am getting `System.Security.SecurityException` error saying access is denied.

```
var fileNme = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
    "Sample.xml");
Debug.WriteLine("app data path " + fileNme.ToString());
```

I am running the application locally on my computer and the eventually deploy to iis. Hopefully someone solution can help me out here.
Thank you.

Comment: File **Sample.xml** must be added under application folder (App_Data or custom folder etc).

Comment: You marked the post with asp.net: are you sure that account IIS is running with is allowed to access specified folder? I think it's not...

Comment: May be your file is read only or your user do not permission to read this file.

Comment: @AVD the file is already inside my app_data folder.

Comment: @Marco i am running the application locally. When i run the application on my personal computer, that happens. I havnt reach IIS and server level as yet.

Comment: Then use `Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/sample.xml")` - It converts virtual path to real path.

Comment: @Andy on my computer, i have full access control. so it cannot be that.

Comment: @AVD i am using lightswitch, i cant add a reference to System.web, hence i cannot use Sever.MapPath or AppDomain.CurrentDomain

Comment: I am not sure this is right but just try out this   select your site Application pool -> Advance Setting -> Process model : Identity - set your User name.

Comment: @Andy .. i havnt deployed as yet. I am running the application from my computer to debug. no application pool there.

Comment: @user3037006 - You need to create WCF RIA service and consume it in your app.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in LightSwitch, but you can try this:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(<<assemblyNamespace>>.<<name_of_page_class>>));
string asmPath = asm.CodeBase;

string app_DataFolder = Path.GetFullPath(Path.GetDirectoryName(asmPath.Remove(0, "file:\\\\\\".Length)) + "\\..\\App_Data");

string filePath = Path.Combine(app_DataFolder, "Sample.xml");
```

Hope it helps!